# How to monitor tcp traffic between my localhost and IP adress

Tags: networking, monitoring, network-interface, bandwidth

I would like to know how to monitor tcp traffic between my `localhost`  and IP address keeping activities in a file. I tried iftop and tcptrack but I can not keep activities in a file. These tools don't target a specify IP address, they're monitoring the interface only :

```
iftop -i eth2 -f "dst port 22"
```

I tried to put the IP address in place of `dst` but it doesn't work.
The idea is for detecting any suspect traffic

Thanks for help

Comment: If you want to snif the relevant traffic of any/or specific interface, you can also use tshark (wireshark's command line tool) which also gives you the ability to save the captured packages into a file. You can also, for example, specify the number of packages, the file's capacity or the time that you want to capture packages from the relevant interface(s). A simple example would be: 
$tshark -i any "host 10.10.10.10" -w my_cap.pcap 
With this command you capture packages from/to 10.10.10.10 IP, from any interface and save the packages to a file.

Comment: @blametheadmin: You culd make this comment into an answer. There must be a way to store truncated packets, if the payload is not important to the asker.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @blametheadmin mentioned in a comment, you can use tshark.  Another option is `tcpdump`:

```
$ tcpdump -w trace.out host <hostname-or-ip>
```

Then later, you can examine that trace with:

```
$ tcpdump -r trace.out
```

Comment: Thanks to answer I would like to do statistic like the -z option with tshark but this tool doesn't accept host or ip with this option

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `tshark` will take the output file produced by `tcpdump` as input.  You may be able to collect the trace using `tcpdump` and then analyze it using `tshark`.

Comment: I used this command `tcpdump -i eth2 -n host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx or dst xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and greater 500 -w trace.out` during 24 hours. I got a file of 355Mb and the tcpdum -r trace.out is pretty hard to understand the meaning of Flags, seq 143:143, ack, win and length
term to do an idea what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

You could use iftop to do bandwidth usage reports as explained in [this serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/598828/122772) answer, by using the `-t` and `-s` switches:

```
-t          use text interface without ncurses
-s num      print one single text output afer num seconds, then quit
-L num      number of lines to print
```

It requires version `iftop-1.0pre3` (2014-01-01) of iftop. In your case, the following example should do the trick to capture 5 hours of traffic of an specific source host:

```
iftop -i eth2 -f "src host x.y.w.z" -t -s 18000 > log.txt &
```

If you want the filter to get `x.y.w.z` as destination you could use `dest` instead, or use only `host` without prefixes if you want to filter both ways.

Comment: Thank nwilder, that's a good answer, less that's scanning all the traffic on the Ethernet device. I would like just monitor a IP address in out traffic.

Comment: Is this host source or destination? You could change the filter to better fit your needs. I'll edit my answer to you..